# Grep text from file name and rename the file the grep-ed text?

Tags: grep

I have many files with the name like below. I want to rename these files with the 5 digits in the middle. For example, rename `N18CMS95WS.12446_950C_wet.txt` to `12446.txt`

```
N18CMS95WS.12446_950C_wet.txt       
N18CMS9WS.12507_900C_wet.txt                
R418WS.15069_800C_wet_air.txt
N18CN85S.13375_850C_dry.txt         
R4195S.13648_950C_dry.txt
```

I tired  `grep ".[[:digit:]]_" N18CMS95WS.12446_950C_wet.txt`to get the`12446`" in the filename, but it does not work. Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `rename`:

```
rename -v 's/.*\.([0-9]+)_.*/$1.txt/' *.txt
```

Here's an alternate solution:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  new="${file#*.}"
  new="${new%%_*}"
  mv -v "$file" "$new".txt
done
```